# How much sunlight would need to be blocked to cancel out atmospheric CO2?

Tags: climate-science

Atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> is trapping too much heat from our star's radiation.  How much light would need to be blocked/reflected before reaching Earth to cancel out the excess heat being trapped by atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: More of an EarthSciencesSE question, imo,  have you checked there for related or duplicates?

Comment: I think this could only be determined by simulating a sophisticated model of the atmosphere and inter-related biosphere. This is far too broad and complex a question to be answered on this site. ... In addition, you are asking for a calculation which you have not attempted to do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This may belong to another SE, but based on [this](https://royalsociety.org/~/media/Royal_Society_Content/policy/publications/2009/8693.pdf), a 2% increase in albedo would roughly offset a doubling of CO2: different models give different numbers and this figure is relatively old in terms of model development & hence quality I suspect.  However it will be in the right ballpark.

Note that you can't fully compensate for CO2: you still get ocean acidification for instance, and you also will get globally weird weather, at least in the engineeringly-plausible approach of dumping a lot of stuff into the stratosphere.  In fact even the 'big mirrors in space' solutions, which are obvious fantasy technically, still do not compensate: the atmosphere with a high CO2 content is just different to that with a lower one.  The best you can do is keep surface temperature under some kind of control.

Surprisingly the stratospheric-aerosol approach is not stupidly expensive: it's expensive but feasible: I think you might need a fleet of 100 planes or something.  You do need to keep doing it though: it's not a once-off fix.

The right search terms to look for are 'Solar Geoengineering' or 'Solar Radiation Management'.

This has traditionally been a slightly taboo area for two reasons.

- It leads people to think that no other fix is needed: we can just keep pumping out CO2 and fix it by pumping sulphuric acid into the stratosphere.  We can't do that in fact for a bunch of reasons (most of which I don't know: I'm not boing coy).
- It might be weaponizable: if you can mess with the climate over some part of the world where people you don't like live you can perhaps engineer harvest failures & the resulting starvation.

I think the current evidence (based on modelling how stratospheric aerosols behave) is that it's *not* weaponizable as you can't localise the effects, and I personally think it might be a reasonable approach to deal with the likely 'overshoot' scenario where CO2 emissions get brought under control but there's a very nasty 50-year window before the system responds.

Comment: +1 I also agree that an edit is advisable.

Comment: @Countto10 I think freedom of speech is different than swearing where it's not really needed: I changed it.

Comment: @LewisMiller You're right, changed

Comment: Even with space mirrors, you can't totally compensate. $\mathrm{CO}_2$ prevents the globe from cooling, so even blocking sunlight will leave you with a warmer troposphere, cooler stratosphere, warmer poles, cooler tropics, warmer nights, cooler days, etc.

Comment: Your reply was so good, that  I was just about to show it to my granny, but how could I ? :)   Sorry for the hassle, and the off topic references.

Comment: @Countto10 No you are right.  There are many things at the moment I want to swear about: this isn't one.  I need to keep my powder dry!

Comment: @SeanLake Yes, you are correct, I will edit it to say that.